# UISheet not showing half way in landscape mode, even with detents set to medium

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to have a `UISheet` which shows half way. My app is landscape only.

When I show the `UISheet`, it just shows at full height, even though I set its detents to be medium.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func openMemoryLog(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let memoryLogViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "memoryLogViewController") {
        if let presentationController = memoryLogViewController.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
            presentationController.detents = [ .medium() ]
            present(memoryLogViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class MemoryLogViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Memory log loaded")
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like. The `MemoryLogViewController` just has a simple text in the middle.

[image: UISheet shown]

I want this shown half way on landscape mode. Is this possible?

Also any hints on how to make the nested `if let` look a bit cleaner?

Comment: There are no properties of UIViewController that will allow you to change size. what you can do is change the size of its view or subviews.